# Twitter Product Cards

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, twitter

I am trying to show twitter product cards.  I have this function in my functions.php .  I validated the twitter card and everything looks good except the product data.  I am trying to display it for only the post type shops.

```
function add_twitter_cards() {
is_singular( 'shops' ); {
$tc_url = get_permalink();
$tc_title = get_the_title();
$tc_description = get_the_excerpt();
$tc_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), full );
$tc_image_thumb = $tc_image[0];
?>
<meta name="twitter:card" value="product" />
<meta name="twitter:site" value="@mytwitter" />
<meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo $tc_title; ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" value="<?php echo $tc_description; ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:url" value="<?php echo $tc_url; ?>" />
<?php if($tc_image) { ?>
<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo $tc_image_thumb; ?>" />
<?php } if($tc_author) { ?>
<meta name="twitter:creator" value="<?php echo $twitter; ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:label1" value="Total Sales" />
<meta name="twitter:data1" value="<?php echo $totalsales ?> <?php _e('of', 'sales'); ?> <?php echo $totalsales; ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:label2" value="Amount Earned" />
<meta name="twitter:data2" value="<?php echo countAmountForAll($post->ID); ?>" />


<?
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few parts here to make this work

- You need set the global `$post` in your function
- You cannot use template tags directly without setting up postdata
- You need to add the post ID to `get_permalink()`
- You have a lot of syntax errors. Compare my code with yours

You can try the following: (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
function add_twitter_cards() 
{
global $post;
    if(is_singular( 'shops' )) {

        setup_postdata($post);
        $tc_url = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $tc_title = get_the_title();
        $tc_description = get_the_excerpt();
        $tc_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
        $tc_image_thumb = $tc_image[0];
        ?>
        <meta name="twitter:card" value="product" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" value="@mytwitter" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo $tc_title; ?>" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" value="<?php echo $tc_description; ?>" />
        <meta name="twitter:url" value="<?php echo $tc_url; ?>" />
        <?php if($tc_image) { ?>
            <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo $tc_image_thumb; ?>" />
        <?php } if($tc_author) { ?>
            <meta name="twitter:creator" value="<?php echo $twitter; ?>" />
            <meta name="twitter:label1" value="Total Sales" />
            <meta name="twitter:data1" value="<?php echo $totalsales; ?> <?php _e('of', 'sales'); ?> <?php echo $totalsales; ?>" />
            <meta name="twitter:label2" value="Amount Earned" />
            <meta name="twitter:data2" value="<?php echo countAmountForAll($post->ID); ?>" />

        <?
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: The twitter card validator says card error.  Thank you though as this does get me closer it seems.